# There is no metric of positive sectional curvature on $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Is there any progress to the famous conjecture of Hopf? There is no metric of positive sectional curvature on $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$. Thanks.

Comment: no $~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Andrey Rekalo has an excellent answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47942/nonnegative-to-positive-curvature. 

Also, I'd like to emphasize the deformation approach to the Hopf conjecture. Amazingly enough, this question is still completely open: 

Does there exist a smooth approximation of the standard metric on $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$ by positively curved metrics?

If you want to show there is no positively curved metric on $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2$, you might first want to show that the answer to this question is no.